# Did Discord.py change its API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

For some reason the code that I have for a Discord bot worked perfectly fine just a few months ago, but now I am getting something saying that 'Bot' has no attribute to certain commands like 'say'

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'say'

Comment: Show us the code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) version 1.0, the "rewrite" version, was officially released on April 8th, and has supplanted the older "async" version 0.16.

You should review the [migration guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) in the documentation to familiarize yourself with the changes.